# react native expo duplicate class kotlin version jdk8 1.8.10 and jdk7 1.7.22

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

i am using react native with expo (version 49.0.7)
when i try to build with eas i get error :
[image]

all the package get this error
i try in the folder of gradle to add this on dependencies:

```
constraints {
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
}
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
}
}
```

and
implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))

but still i get this errors